# Learning How To Code In Smali by converting java2smali

Tags: smali

I've been trying to learn smali for a while now, it seems to difficult so i plan on learning through converting little .java codes to .smali and studying the structure.. How can i convert a simple HelloWorld to .smali?

`public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World");`

Answer (score 2):

If you have HelloWorld.java:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Then you can do the following to compile it, convert it to a dex file, and finally disassemble it to smali code

```
javac HelloWorld.java
dx --dex --output=HelloWorld.dex HelloWorld.class
baksmali HelloWorld.dex -o HelloWorld
```

And then the smali code will be in HelloWorld/HelloWorld.smali

Comment: Thanks JesusFreke. I'm sorry if I sound stupid right now,  where should I place the ' javac Hello world. java'  command?

Comment: You would type it into a terminal.

Comment: I tried This                                                                                        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin>javac C:\Users\Given\Downloads\MyApplication\app\src\main\java\HelloWorld.java dx --dex --output=HelloWorld.dex HelloWorld.class baksmali HelloWorld.dex -o HelloWorld"

     ............And i got this Error     " javac: invalid flag: --dex
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options"

Comment: Ummm. You do realize that that is 3 separate commands, right? :)